# calculating total vat for sales

Tags: sql

i need to calculate the total  vat(15% of total sales) estimated for the total sales. im struggling with this query i first tried a select sum then  which didnt work-->

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS total_sales,
       SUM(price) * 0.15 AS fifteen_percent
FROM   sales;
```

**here a is a picture of the products table**
[image: products]

**here is a picture of the sales table**
[image: sales table]

any help would be greatly appreciated !, thank you.

Comment: Your query works for me (Postgres) w/o problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(price*quantity) AS total_sales,
       SUM(price*quantity) * 0.15 AS fifteen_percent
FROM   sales 
JOIN products ON sales.prod_id = products.prod_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wawrzyniec is correct, but you can also use a Windowed function for aggregation.

```
           SELECT DISTINCT prod_name, 
                           SUM(price) OVER(PARTITION BY prod_name) * quantity as total_sales, 
                           (SUM(price) OVER(PARTITION BY prod_name) * quantity) * 0.15 as  fifteen_percent    
           FROM sales 
           INNER JOIN products ON sales.prod_id = products.prod_id;
```